# Error: Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

From time to time (5-7 times per day) I have received such an exception "502: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" with message "Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated." and category "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher".

Answer (score 0):

I am using Azure Functions 4.x with .NET 7 and from time to time (5-7 times per day) I have received such an error 502 "Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated." with category "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher". It took a lot of time to find the reason and solution for this issue.

Therefore, I'd like to share the solution with the community.

1. The first case that can cause such an error is old packages that are not competible with dotnet-isolated. Make sure that you are not using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blobs and so on. You can find the same solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1121514/i-have-an-error-(failed-to-start-a-new-language-wo?orderby=newest .
2. The second case that can cause such an error is an outdated Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker nuget package, make sure you are using 1.14.1 version as Azure developers have made some usefull changes in this version. You can find more details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/pull/1508 .

Comment: I am on .net 7 and same versions you mentioned. Unfortunately I am still getting the error.

Comment: Same here. Have you resolved this @SharifYazdian ?

Comment: no, unfortunately, still struggling